# Conditional coloring in excel/pivot

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, pivot-table

[image][image]

Hi,

I am trying to set up a sheet, where I analyze and compare data within' a pivot table (on the left) with data extracted manually from a data source (on the right). Assume that the table on the right is a portfolio, and the table on the left is a stat overview of all possible positions. Column "S" is given as:

> =IF(ISNA(MATCH(O7,$B$7:$B$119,0)),"", "MISA")

which basically lets me know if my position is on the list on the left, and column "A" similarly is given as:

> =IF(ISNA(MATCH(B8,$O$4:$O$19,0)),"","1")

which lets me know whether the asset within the list is held in the portfolio.

So my inquiry now, is basically that I would like the list on left to have its row colored, whenever the asset is held in the portfolio, thus whenever there is a "1" in column "A", then that particular row should be colored. I have naturally played around with the conditional formatting, but cant seem to get it to work. Dont know if it is due to the fact that it is a pivot table vs. the function in column "A"???

Thanks,
Psb

Comment: So you just want to highlight a row if its its A column value is 1. Am i right?

Comment: @Siva - correct. It seems so simple, but whenever I use the conditional formatting function the total pivot table is colored??

Comment: Can you share the screen print of Edit Rule of Conditional formatting? I can guide you on it

Comment: @pnuts - this was perfect! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that your range does't have '$'before the range column and row numbers. '$' refers to static values. So in my below screen, '$A4' indicates to Static column which is A and dynamic row number. Similarly the area on which rule has to be applied is dynamic, which refers from 'B4:G23' cells, so whenever A4 =1 then 'B4:G4' will highlight. similarly A5=1 then B5:G5...

[image]

PS:Please note i didn't apply the rule on any pivot table but just on a normal range. The same thing should hold good for pivot table also.

Comment: Hi @Siva
Thanks for the answer, but is still doesn't work ?? Now I have NO $ signs. futhermore: The rule:  "Formula =$A4=1" should apply for the whole row A.